# Javascript appending DIV tag dynamically

Tags: javascript

I want to append the content of an already defined "old div" tag to the "new div" tag dynamically but as I'm new to javascript i don't have any idea that how to do this. The code i tried is attached below.
And one more question, how to remove that appended div tag dynamically?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function add() {

var i = document.getElementById( 'old' );
var d = document.getElementById( 'new' );
d.appendChild( i );
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="old">
Content of old div
</div>

<div id="new">
</div>
<button onclick="add">Add</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you use a library? [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for example

Comment: @RichardD thanks for the suggestion. Actually I am not so good in jquerry. I prefer it doing js way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, except for one thing. Change button tag to:

```
<button onclick="add();">Add</button>
```

Horizontal lines around the new div in the following code will clearly show you it is working.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function add() {
                console.log("In add");
                var i = document.getElementById( 'old' );
                var d = document.getElementById( 'new' );
                d.appendChild( i );
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="old">
            Content of old div
        </div>

        <hr/>
        <div id="new">
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <button onclick="add();">Add</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
var iContent = document.getElementById( 'old' ).innerHTML;
document.getElementById( 'new' ).innerHTML = iContent; // assuming you already have new div
```